# Delete contents of a table view based on the check-box value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs,thats why im asking this simple question.

I have a list of contacts(displayed in a listview).Each listview has one checkbox.

There is one delete button at the bottom of listview.What i want to implement is that,app should delete the contacts based on the value of check-box.

When i tried in this way:

in controller,

```
$scope.checkBox = function (index)
{
    alert(index);
}
```

in html,

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in completeList| filter:search">
        <td ng-click="detailView($index,'detailFlag')">
            <div><img width="100px" height="50px"  ng-src="{{n.gender_image}}" > </div>         
        <div>{{n.name}}</div>
        <div>{{n.email}}</div>
        <div>{{n.phone}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model='Selected' ng-click="checkBox($index)" >
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

here i can get the index of the listview cell.

But im stuck,with how to identify whether the check-box is checked or not and remove the contacts based on check box bool value.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share a little bit mor code (or better yet prepare a fiddle). For example, how is this `checkBox()` function used ?

Comment: Are you using `ngRepeat` ? Let us see your data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your checkbox, you currently have:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model='Selected' ng-click="checkBox($index)" >
```

So the value, whether the checkbox is selected, is stored in **one** variable for **all** inputs!

Instead, assign the `ng-model` to let's say the `selected` property of the current item in the `ng-repeat` scope:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in completeList| filter:search">
        <td ng-click="detailView($index,'detailFlag')">
            <div><img width="100px" height="50px"  ng-src="{{n.gender_image}}" > </div>         
        <div>{{n.name}}</div>
        <div>{{n.email}}</div>
        <div>{{n.phone}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model='n.selected' ng-click="checkBox(n)" >
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and change your `checkBox` function like so:

```
$scope.checkBox = function (item)
{
    if (item.selected === true) {
        // item selected
    } else {
        // item not selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer said you have to bind the checkbox state to an attribute of n.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="n in completeList| filter:search">
      <td ng-click="detailView($index,'detailFlag')">

        <div><img width="100px" height="50px"  ng-src="{{n.gender_image}}" > </div>         
         <div>{{n.name}}</div>
         <div>{{n.email}}</div>
         <div>{{n.phone}}</div>
      </td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="n.selected"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

But the checkBox($index) with ngClick is not needed at all. At least with the current implementation which just sets the selected status.

Then this could be your code delete button logic:

```
<button ng-click="deleteItems()">Delete</button>

// controller code
$scope.deleteItems = function() {
  $scope.completeList = $scope.completeList.filter(
    function(item) {
      return !item.selected
    }
  );
}
```

You see you just have to change the underlying model.

Comment: thanks for your answer.i wondered deletion is this much easy.

Comment: You also might want to consider a library such as underscore or lodash to use collection functions like filter. This increases cross browser compability.